# React redux-form initialValues isn't loading properly

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have tried to figure it out how to load Fields on redux-form but I don't why it isn't working properly. I have made a project on Sandbox and I'll put the link below, if someone could help me with this bug, or issue, plz do it and I'd really appreciate that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/6k85yv8k3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you are decorating the component is important. First it needs to be decorated with reduxForm() and then connect()

After changing the order in your code, it is working as expected - https://codesandbox.io/s/rw71o23k6q

You can also refer to the documentation here - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/examples/initializeFromState/src/InitializeFromStateForm.js

Another missing piece is, setting 
  enableReinitialize: true in reduxForm. Here is the documentation on it - https://redux-form.com/6.0.2/examples/initializefromstate/

Answer (score 0):

Use reduxForm HOC to read the initial values as in https://codesandbox.io/s/142p8v0roq (FormProfile.js) or check the documentation at https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/examples/initializeFromState/src/InitializeFromStateForm.js

Comment: Hey I didn’t understand you put values as constant I want to get from action . I changed yours to get from reducer and doesn’t work as well :(